# Infusionsoft PHP SDK retrieve and display data from custom field

Tags: php, infusionsoft

So the gist of this question is, I have an affiliate portal that users can submit leads through, this information is then passed along and stored as a contact in a campaign on Infusion Soft, What I cannot figure out is how I can go the other way and display data from a custom field in the contact card on IS back on the page. In this case the status of the lead. By default it will say "processing" but when a team member either denies or accepts the lead I want it to display that back in the portal.

Using the PHP iSDK.

My portal looks as follows, 
[portal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2EGb.jpg)
The leads in there currently are stored in the wordpress database as well as in infusionsoft. When loading the page it loads the values from the WP database. I would like it to be such that the "status" reflects what is in the custom field on infusion soft for each lead.

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$path .= "/scripts/isdk.php";
require_once ($path);
$app = new iSDK();
if ($app->cfgCon("rz297")) {                                                              
    $returnFields = array('_LoanStatus');
    $conDat = $app->dsLoad("Contact", 43434, $returnFields);                                    
}
```

Right now I just have the one contact ID in their to test getting the value of the custom field, but I would need to be able to get it from multiple contacts, i.e. the leads

Answer (score 1):

The initial question has been updated significantly, and now it sounds like another question, so the first part of my answer may look irrelevant, but it answers the initial question.

**How to retrieve custom field value**

Take a look [at this documentation example](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#contact-retrieve-a-contact). It shows you may pass *selectedFields*. Add your custom field name to this array to get its value in a response. Note, for API requests this name has to be added an underscore in the beginning, for example: *_MyLeadField*.

Here's one more documentation link, it describes [where to find custom fields names in Infusionsoft UI](http://help.infusionsoft.com/related-articles/backend-database-names-for-custom-fields)

**How to retrieve information of multiple contacts**

As shown in [documentation](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-query-a-data-table), you may query Infusionsoft database using **IN** statement. As you use *iSDK*, here's an example using this library that should work:

```
$returnFields = array('Id', '_LoanStatus');
$app->dsQuery("Contact", 1000, 0, array('Id' => array(123, 432, 455)), $returnFields);
```

Comment: I have the retrieving of the custom field and displaying figured out, but only if i have that specific contact ID, Essentially at this point what i cannot figure out is how i can retrieve the custom field from more than one contact and then display that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect your question updates and answer this question too.